# Как правильно настроить репликацию между двумя нодами с помощью repmgr?

Tags: postgresql

Не особо силен в терминалогии и настройке отказоустойчивых систем, но сверху прилетает задача и начинаешь открывать, для себя все новые и новые горизонты.(человек который придумывал схему, ни разу ее не внедрял)

взял за основу [данную инструкцию](https://habr.com/ru/company/etagi/blog/314000/), так как она наиболее подходит для решения поставленной задачи. Имеется 2 ноды с развернутыми на них Postgresql-10. Хосты прописал, ssh-ключи раскидал, отключил автостарт postgresql. Настроил repmgr. Главный сервер зарегестрировал как мастер.

```
    master: 
      pg_hba.conf (добавлено внизу):
      local   replication   repmgr                              trust
      host    replication   repmgr      127.0.0.1/32            trust
      host    replication   repmgr      192.168.1.0/24          trust
      local   repmgr        repmgr                              trust
      host    repmgr        repmgr      127.0.0.1/32            trust
      host    repmgr        repmgr      192.168.1.0/24          trust

      host    all              all       0.0.0.0/32              md5

   postgresql.conf(добавлено снизу):
      listen_addresses='*'
      wal_level = 'replica'
      archive_mode = on
      wal_log_hints = on
      wal_keep_segments = 0
      archive_command = 'cd .'
      max_replication_slots = 5 
      hot_standby = on
      shared_preload_libraries = 'repmgr'
      max_connections = 800
      max_wal_senders = 10 
      port = 5433
      pg_stat_statements.max = 10000
      pg_stat_statements.track = all

  /etc/repmgr.conf:
      cluster=test
      node_id=1
      node_name=node1
      use_replication_slots=1
      conninfo='host=pghost195 port=5433 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr'
      pg_bindir='/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin'
      data_directory='/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/'

slave:
  /etc/repmgr.conf:
      cluster=avanpost_test
      node_id=2
      node_name=node2
      use_replication_slots=1
      conninfo='host=pghost196 port=5433  user=repmgr dbname=repmgr'
      pg_bindir='/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin'
      data_directory='/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/'
```

Хочу зарегестрировать сервер как slave командой:

```
rm -rf main/*  (удаляю данные из /var/lib/postgresql/10/main)
repmgr -h pghost195 -p 5433 -U repmgr -d repmgr -D main -f /etc/repmgr.conf --copy-external-config- 
files=pgdata --verbose standby clone
```

данные приходят, файлы появляются в папке.
при выполнении команды

```
pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main start
```

получаю ошибку:

```
postgres@user-virtual-machine:/home/user$ pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main start
ожидание запуска сервера....2020-05-06 19:41:10.065 GMT [4643] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  открыть каталог конфигурации "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/conf.d" не удалось: Нет такого файла или каталога
2020-05-06 19:41:10.065 GMT [4643] ВАЖНО:  файл конфигурации "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf" содержит ошибки
 прекращение ожидания
pg_ctl: не удалось запустить сервер
Изучите протокол выполнения.
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вам уже ответили `ВАЖНО: файл конфигурации "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf" содержит ошибки`

Comment: @Hellseher, это я и сам прекрасно вижу. Вопрос в том, почему данный конфиг сработал на мастере, но не работает на слейве?

Comment: Я не сталкивался с репликацией и с подобным поведением, задам глупый вопрос, вдруг что прояснится :) Может, в папке /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/conf.d на одном сервере есть какие-то дополнительные конфигурации, а на другом сервере такого нет? Возможно, на разных нодах у Вас установлены разные расширения или вообще разные ОС и от этого зависит место хранения дополнительных конфигов?

Comment: @asvetl. в postgresql.conf на мастере был параметр папки для кастомных параметров со значением "conf.d". закоментил его и собственно сервак запустился